# Reordering Items in a Grouped List in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a Task List View in SwiftUI:

```
struct TaskListView: View {

@EnvironmentObject var listViewModel: ListViewModel

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        if listViewModel.items.isEmpty {
            Text("No items")
        } else {
            List {
                ForEach(listViewModel.filteredItems){
                    item in ListRowView(item: item)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            withAnimation(.linear){
                                listViewModel.updateItem(item: item)
                            }
                        }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: listViewModel.deleteItem)
                .onMove(perform: listViewModel.moveItem)
                                    
            }.listStyle(.sidebar)
        }
    }
    //.navigationTitle()
        .navigationBarItems(
            leading: EditButton(),
            trailing: NavigationLink("Add", destination: AddView()))
}}

struct ListRowView: View {
let item: ItemModel
var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Image(systemName: item.isCompleted ? "checkmark.circle": "circle")
            .foregroundColor(item.isCompleted ? .green: .red)
        Text(item.title)
        Spacer()
    }.font(.body)//.title2)
        .padding(.vertical,4)//8)
}}
```

With the following View Model:

```
class ListViewModel: ObservableObject {
@Published var items: [ItemModel] = [] {
    didSet {
        saveItems()
    }
}

var filteredItems: [ItemModel] {
    items.filter { $0.partOfDay.rawValue.contains("morning")}
}

let itemsKey: String = "items_list"

init() {
    getItems()
}

func getItems() {
    guard
        let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: itemsKey),
        let savedItems = try? JSONDecoder().decode([ItemModel].self, from: data)
    else { return }
    self.items = savedItems
}

func deleteItem(indexSet: IndexSet) {
    items.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
}

func moveItem(from: IndexSet, to: Int) {
    items.move(fromOffsets: from, toOffset: to)
}

func addItem(title: String, partOfDay: PartOfDay) {
    let newItem = ItemModel(title: title, partOfDay: partOfDay, isCompleted: false)
    items.append(newItem)
}

func updateItem(item: ItemModel) {
    if let index = items.firstIndex { (existingItem) -> Bool in
        return existingItem.id == item.id
    } {
        items[index] = item.updateCompletion()
    }
}

func saveItems() {
    if let encodedData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(items) {
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(encodedData, forKey: itemsKey)
    }
}}
```

I'm trying to re-order filtered items in the list and it doesn't work - items get back to their previous order. If I show all the items from the model without filtering (published property) reordering works correctly. How do I reorder filtered items?
(my list has to be grouped by day parts - morning, afternoon, evening and night)

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI it's best if your classes are only for model data. For view data use the `View` struct, i.e. for the various visual representations of the model data, sorted, moves, filtered etc. To filtered items you just make a computed var:

```
struct ItemsView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var store: ModelStore

    @State var searchTerm = "morning"

    // since body is called whenever store or searchTerm changes it means this var will also be called
    var filteredItems: [ItemModel] {
        store.items.filter { item in
            item.partOfDay.contains(searchTerm)
        }
    }
```

For the no item case a neat trick is an `.overlay`, e.g.

```
List(filteredItems) { item in
    ...
}
.overlay {
    if store.items.isEmpty {
        Text("No items")
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do I put onDelete and onMove in this case?

Comment: I suppose those go in the store and you probably should disable moving when the filter is active.